# Prevent factory_girl from loading spec/factories/*.rb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, factory-bot

In a `rails` project, I'd like to put `factory_girl` factories in `spec/support/factories/` instead of `spec/factories/` (since the later already contains specs for "factory" classes).

Here is my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = [File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'support', 'factories')]
# FactoryGirl.factories.clear
# FactoryGirl.reload

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include AuthenticationHelper
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

But when I run `rspec`, files in `spec/factories` still get loaded twice (by both `factory_girl` and `rspec`), resulting in duplicate test execution.

I don't think `FactoryGirl.factories.clear` can help me, neither `FactoryGirl.reload`, since they won't prevent the tests to be run.

Is there any way to just prevent `factory_girl` to load `spec/factories/` ?

(Using `ruby 1.9.3p327`, `rails 3.2.9`, `factory_girl 4.1.0`, `factory_girl_rails 4.1.0`, `rspec-core 2.12.2`, and `rspec-rails 2.12.0`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an initializer (any file in `config/initializers`, say `config/initializers/factory_girl.rb`) with this line:

```
FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths.delete(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec/factories'))
```

Then remove the line `FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = ...` line from `spec_helper.rb`, which you shouldn't need.

See the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/factory_girl/FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths) for more on the `definition_file_paths` method.

Comment: I updated my answer: you have to put this line in an initializer file so that it gets loaded before loading `factory_girl`.