# a way to prevent factory_girl_rails from making factories/MODEL.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I make all of my factories in factories.rb and wonder if there is a way to prevent the making of factories/MODEL.rb when I use the rails g model generator.

I see this question [Prevent factory_girl from loading spec/factories/*.rb files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119501/prevent-factory-girl-from-loading-spec-factories-rb-files) but really want to bypass factories/MODEL.rb altogether (ie not have in repo).

thx for any help

Comment: `rails generate model MyModel -t nil` worked for me, try it!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the factory_girl_rails gem, factory_girl is configured as a fixture replacement for RSpec.

I was able to disable the factory generator using the following in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.generators do |generate|
  generate.test_framework(
    :rspec,
    :fixture => false,
    :fixture_replacement => nil
  )
end
```